# how can i take the current time in mysql query?

Tags: php, mysql

I have a database which i created via PHPmyadmin. And I have problem with the time columns/calculation.

```
table name = course

..course_name | section_ID | Dr_ID | time_start | time_end | location 
...................................| 10:00:00 | 10:20:00 < //i but the
                                                        value like this
```

And the type of `(| time_start | time_end |) = Time` < //like this in PHPmyadmin

And my query doesn't work. I guess the problem is .time(). in the query:

```
$query2 = "SELECT location FROM sections where Dr_ID = 1
           AND time_start <= ".time()." and time_end > ".time();
```

Comment: could you please paste the create query for tabale here?

Comment: Are you looking for `time_start <= now() and time_end > now()` perhaps?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `time()` function returns a unix timestamp, you *time_start* field seems to be a mysql TIME type you need to convert one of them to be able to make a proper comparison.

You can use `date("H:i:s",time())` instead of `time()`, which might get you what you want

Or you need to convert your *time_start* *time_end* fields to unix timestamp UNIX_TIMESTAMP() - you will need to concatenate the date in front of your *time_start*.

Answer (score 0):

try to use,If I understand correctly,

```
SELECT location FROM sections 
where Dr_ID = 1 AND (now() between time_start and time_end )
```